# Cross border gifting (US and Canada)

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, gift-tax

I wanted to know what's the tax implication if I am a US citizen gifting money to someone in Canada who is neither a Canadian nor a US citizen. Does the gift tax applies?
Share your resources please.

Thanks

Comment: What amount are you gifting? You can gift $17K per person per year without having  US gift tax liability, or needing to file a gift tax return (Form 709).

Answer (score 2):

The US gift tax applies to the donor, it doesn't matter who/where the donee is (except for certain exempt donees like charities, or specific qualified donations like tuition or medical bills payments).

You can read more details in the [instructions for the form 709](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i709#en_US_2022_publink16784xd0e465), including the [exemptions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i709#en_US_2022_publink16784xd0e538) and [exclusions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i709#en_US_2022_publink16784xd0e649).